# php loop output

Tags: php, loops

I have a smiliar loop:

```
$names = "
[$name , $surname]
";

echo "$names";
```

The result:

```
[Mario,Rossi]
[Aberto,rossi]
[Giovanni,Rossi]
```

i would this output:

```
[Mario,Rossi],
[Aberto,rossi],
[Giovanni,Rossi]
```

Without , in the last result 
* I can't know the number of results in the loop

Comment: Why don't you know the loop count?

Comment: Could you show all your code, please?

Comment: @lonesomeday - suppose that there is more code to come :) I don't think so....

Comment: @MichalPlško Well, that code couldn't produce that output, so clearly there's something else...

Comment: @binarious: Why would you need to know the loop count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple array implosion will do the trick here:

```
$names[] = "[$name, $surname]";
echo implode(",\n", $names);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$names[] = "
[$name , $surname]
";

$comma_sep = implode(",", $names);

echo "<pre>{$comma_sep}</pre>";
```

The data should be pre-formatted with `<pre>` tags if you want to use your line breaks like that.

Comment: I would remove the pre tags. Although php is normally used as a server side language it can be used through the command line where the newlines have significance and the pre tags would be incorrect. PHP server side can also be used to return a file other than html. For example it can be used to return a plain text file.

Comment: @MitMaro I used his variable design and he said he wanted an output with line breaks (without OP using \n). I wouldn't do it like that, but I don't know how the OP intends to use it, either.

Comment: He didn't use `\n` he used a literal line break in his string.

Comment: @Truth Don't you love it when vagueness is matched with expected mind reading? :)